# Masking minimum value in every column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I have the following matrix:

```
matrix = np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)
```

I want to mask the minimum values in each column. The solution below masks the minimum values in every row when `axis=1`, however when `axis=0` it only masks the min value in the first column.

`matrix_masked = np.ma.masked_where(matrix == np.resize(matrix.min(axis=0),[matrix.shape[0],1]),matrix)`

Is there something else I should change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sums don't need reshaped into columns find the correct values on axis 0.

So Try without the resize:

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(5)
matrix = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(4, 6))

matrix_masked = np.ma.masked_where(matrix == matrix.min(axis=0), matrix)

print("Matrix")
print(matrix)
print("Masked Matrix")
print(matrix_masked)
```

```
Matrix
[[99 78 61 16 73  8]
 [62 27 30 80  7 76]
 [15 53 80 27 44 77]
 [75 65 47 30 84 86]]
```

```
Masked Matrix
[[99 78 61 -- 73 --]
 [62 -- -- 80 -- 76]
 [-- 53 80 27 44 77]
 [75 65 47 30 84 86]]
```

---

Or [@Corralien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15239951/corralien)'s suggestion use [MaskedArray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.baseclass.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray):

```
matrix_masked = np.ma.MaskedArray(matrix, matrix == np.min(matrix, axis=0))
```

Comment: Same here with MaskedArray: `np.ma.MaskedArray(matrix, matrix == np.min(matrix, axis=0))`